# Choose file prompt, show hidden files? Applescript objtc

Tags: xcode, macos, operating-system, applescript

I use this to get a prompt where i can select a file

```
set thePath to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "whatever)
```

How can i see hidden files in the "choose folder with prompt"?
Allowing to see hidden files in finder doesn't do anything different.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add `with invisibles`:

```applescript
set thePath to quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
 (choose folder with prompt "whatever" with invisibles)
```

You can find the full syntax of the `choose folder` command in the Standard Additions dictionary: in AppleScript Editor, press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-O</kbd> (or select `File > Open Dictionary...`) and select `StandardAdditions.osax` from the list.